# Redirecting to Microsoft account selection after logout, how to skip Microsoft account popup and directly redirect to logout?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I'm currently facing an issue with the logout functionality in my web application. After clicking on the logout button, instead of immediately redirecting to the logout page, I'm being redirected to a Microsoft popup that asks which account to logout. However, I would like to skip this step and have the application directly redirect to the logout page.

This is what I have in my app.module.ts:

After user clicking logout, it is redirecting to Microsoft page , for single user there is no use to show which page to select as I showed in image, how can I resolve this issue by not directing to Microsoft page ?
[image]

```
MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientId, // This is your client ID
        authority: environment.authority, // This is your tenant ID
        redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,// This is your redirect URI,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.logoutURL
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
          [environment.apiBaseUrl, [environment.apiScope]],
      ])
    }),
```

And here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "", loadChildren: () => import('./pages/layout/layout.module').then(m => m.LayoutModule),
  // canActivateChild: [MsalGuard]
},
{
  path: "sign-in", loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo:"page", pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Here is my logout function:

```
this.authService.logoutRedirect({
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/'
    });
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/sign-in');
}
```