# How to sign in without redirecting to Microsoft page for account selection?

Tags: angular, angularjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

when I'm try to sign in, I'm redirected to a Microsoft page for account selection, and I want to know how to sign in without being redirected. I provide my screenshot of Microsoft redirection for reference
[image]

I'm trying to sign-in my web application without directing to Microsoft account selection page the screenshot I referred .

This is what I have in my app.module.ts:

```
MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientId, // This is your client ID
        authority: environment.authority, // This is your tenant ID
        redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,// This is your redirect URI,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.logoutURL
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
          [environment.apiBaseUrl, [environment.apiScope]],
      ])
    }),

And here is my app-routing.module.ts:

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "", loadChildren: () => import('./pages/layout/layout.module').then(m => m.LayoutModule),
  // canActivateChild: [MsalGuard]
},
{
  path: "sign-in", loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo:"page", pathMatch: 'full' },
];

Here is my login function:
 login() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService.loginRedirect({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting to Microsoft account selection after logout, how to skip Microsoft account popup and directly redirect to logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456286/redirecting-to-microsoft-account-selection-after-logout-how-to-skip-microsoft-a)